# Key error on plone customscriptadapter [ploneformgen]

Tags: python, plone, ploneformgen

Based on: http://www.sixfeetup.com/blog/how-to-allow-users-to-create-site-content-using-ploneformgen

I tried this custom script adapter:

```
pasta = context.portal_url.getPortalObject()['conteudo']
(comment) The form being submitted so we can access its contents
form = request.form

(comment) Create a unique ID
from DateTime import DateTime
identidade = str(DateTime().millis())

(comment) Create a new Page (Document)
pasta.invokeFactory("Document", id=identidade, title=form['nome-completo'])

(comment) Set the reference for our new Page
obj=pasta[identidade]

(comment) Set the values for the content of the Page; use the short names of each item in the form
(comment) (which you can see in the URL if you are viewing one of the fields directly)
obj.setContentType('text/html')
obj.setText(form['formacao'])


(comment) Reindexed the Page in the site
obj.reindexObject()
```

But I'm getting this weird error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
-Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 60, in publish
-Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
-Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
-Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
-Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 26, in _call
-Module Products.CMFFormController.FormController, line 384, in validate
-Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
-Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
-Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerValidator, line 58, in __call__
-Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
-Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
-Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
-Module Products.PloneHotfix20130618.spamProtect, line 33, in _patched_bindAndExec
-Module Products.PloneHotfix20121106.python_scripts, line 63, in _patched_bindAndExec
-Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
-Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
-Module script, line 20, in fgvalidate_base
  - <FSControllerValidator at /course/statistics/fgvalidate_base used for /course/statistics/create/form>
-Line 20
-Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.form, line 574, in fgvalidate
-Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.form, line 622, in fgProcessActionAdapters
-Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.customScriptAdapter, line 187, in onSuccess
-Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.customScriptAdapter, line 218, in executeCustomScript
-Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
-Module Products.PloneHotfix20130618.spamProtect, line 33, in _patched_bindAndExec
-Module Products.PloneHotfix20121106.python_scripts, line 63, in _patched_bindAndExec
-Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
-Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
-Module script, line 15, in Processing Data
  - <PythonScript at /course/statistics/create/form/formcustomscriptadapter.2016-03-21.4473916570/Processing Data>
-Line 15
-Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 83, in guarded_getitem
-Module Products.PloneHotfix20130618.get, line 38, in __getitem__
-**KeyError: '1458833943942'**
```

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: As Products.PloneHotfix20130618 is throwing the error, you could remove that product (a.k.a. addon) in case you're riding with a recent Plone-version, because then additionally installing the hotfix is not needed anymore.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried searching (plonehotfix20130618) on the products/add-ons section, but, unfortunately, i didn't find it...is it somewhere else?

Comment: Well to remove it, you'd search in the buildout-config for the product-name, remove it, run buildout, restart server, HTH.

Comment: thanks. but i can't find it anywhere... do you know if it's included somewhere else? these are the products that are listed on buildout.cfg: PIL,
   Products.CMFPlone,
   plone.app.iterate,
   plone.app.openid,
   Products.CMFPlacefulWorkflow,
   Products.PloneFormGen,
   zope.egg,
thanks in advance

Comment: i'm using : Plone 4.1.3 (4112),
CMF 2.2.4,
Zope 2.13.10,
Python 2.6.5,
PIL unknown

Answer (score 1):

answer: i just changed the line

```
obj=pasta[identidade]
```

to:

```
obj = pasta.get('identidade',pasta)
```

and it worked :-)